# JSON date with offset to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am developing an Cocoa application on the Mac and I am consuming a WCF service which is returning me a JSON date which comes from a SQL Server DATETIMEOFFSET field. The JSON object returned from the service including the date fields is outlined below:

```
{
    "ObjectId": 1,
    "Name": "My Object Name",
    "Description": "My Object Description",   
    "CreateDate": {
        "DateTime": "/Date(1306481778297)/",
        "OffsetMinutes": 0
    },
    "LastModifiedDate": {
        "DateTime": "/Date(1306936930427)/",
        "OffsetMinutes": 0
    }
}
```

My question is how do I convert the CreateDate and LastModifiedDate fields to NSDate objects?

I attempted to create a NSDateFormatter and abstract the value that way. However this works for simple string dates or the standard JSON date (/Date(1306936930427)/) but not the the date object containing the date and the offset.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]
NSString *creationDate = [myObject valueForKey:@"CreateDate"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:creationDate];
```

Any help on this one will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, extract the number from the string (e.g. 1306936930427); [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) might come in handy for this. Then divide it by 1000.0 and use NSDate's `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` class method to get your NSDate.