# What is the format that date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, datetime

I need to know what format this date, the format is this 1394567523572-0300 here, this is a timestamp ?

Format:

```
1394567523572-0300
```

Comment: probably some form of time interval since reference... you get it from JSON request?

Comment: How shall we know without any indication of the source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON date with offset to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751999/json-date-with-offset-to-nsdate)

Comment: @Volker really? I disagree.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a non-standard format consisting of the number of milliseconds since the epoch (`1394567523572`) and a time zone offset (`0300`). If I had to guess this "format" is intended to mean `2014-03-11T19:52:03.572Z`, with [some time zone that has a UTC+03:00 offset.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.2B03:00.2C_C)

Answer (score 3):

It's the number of milliseconds since *Unix epoch* (1-Jan-1970) with the addition of a timezone (`-0300`).

See this [online epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the number of milliseconds from Jan 1 1970 (otherwise known as Unix time * 1000) along with a timezone offset of -3 hours.

The Unix timestamp of 1394567523 is the equivalent of Tue, 11 Mar 2014 19:52:03